# How to open .dbs file and view its data?

Tags: sqlbase

I tried to open .dbs file using SQLBase and Open Office but it can't open. In file viewer lite, .dbs opens but like below image. What should I do to open that file?

[image: merchant.dbs in text view:--]

[image: merchant.dbs in Hex view:--]

Comment: origin of this file ? Try to view the mime type via "file your.dbs" (tried to open it with sqlite3 ?)

Comment: I tried to open this file using sqlite 3 but can't open.  original file:-- https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-a_RHhYuQqkUUdiQ1kyRjU4clE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: A quick web search suggests that the .dbs file extension is used by a number of different applications including several database products. You will have a much better chance of reliability extracting the data if you know (1) the application that created the file, and/or (2) the structure of the table(s) it contains.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a sqlite database you can download a sqlite Editor to open it.

Comment: .dbs is a Gupta SQLBase database file.  You do need the correct version of SQLBase installed to be able to Unload it . It will be encrypted , so there is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

.dbs is a [Gupta Technologies SQLBase](http://www.opentext.com/what-we-do/products/specialty-technologies/opentext-gupta-development-tools-databases/opentext-gupta-sqlbase)  database file.  You do need the correct version of SQLBase installed to be able to Unload it . It will be encrypted , so there is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

SQLBase is 256-bit AES encrypted. There is no way to meaningful read the data without first UNLOADing it using Gupta SQLTalk. See the attached SQLBase Language reference , specifically 'UNLOAD' to get your data and schema out of your dbs version , and then (optionally) 'LOAD' to get you data into another version . The attached manual is for v9 , but LOAD and UNLOAD work the same no matter which version of SQLbase . See: [SQLBase Language Reference](http://enos.itcollege.ee/~priit/(I216)%20Ab-de%20administreerimine/SQLBase%20admin%20juhendid/LANG.PDF)

Answer (score -1):

You can Open the Shema files using dbShema software(Pro)
[Click here](https://dbschema.com/download.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).